# Make edits on dynamically loaded data using jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dropdown, on its change I need to load the contents related to it on the same page. Which I did using jQuery. Now the question is how do I make edits on this data and store it on my database. If I am wrong in using jQuery for loading my data then what else should I use? I am using PHP as my server side scripting language.

More detail -

Simply taking there a list of details I need to display as per the country you select, which I am displaying currently in a nice grid(textboxes)!

Now the data from this grid should be copied to another textbox on "**EDIT**" button click from where I edit them and store it in my database. I am not able to make the values copy into a another textbox

Comment: The question is too short. Add more details. What kind of edits do you wand to do? When these edits should be performed? I guess changing the data from PHP is not a problem for you. So you just need to invoke such PHP code from your web page (e.g. using jQuery)...

Comment: _I am not able to make the values copy into a another textbox_ Don't copy the data, just load the data similarly as you did it for your _nice grid_ ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

- Display the data in some form of editable `div`, `textarea`, or other element.
- Make a hidden field somewhere and when you display the data
- Set the row id from your database to the hidden field
- On your change event, grab the id from the hidden field along with the edited data.
- Using Jquery/ajax, send that data to a php page that will save thee data to your database using the passed in id.

**You could do that.**

However, if it were me (and if you're not married to your current databse / mySQL etc..), I would use [parse.com](https://parse.com/). The service is free up to a significant amount of usage (which Ive never come close to) and it really simplifies everything. See the below post if you're interested in that approach:

[Save and retrieve user input from database with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881449/save-and-retrieve-user-input-from-database-with-javascript/27882356)