# combine two ajax call - storing multiple post variables in url

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I would like to combie these two ajax call for I would like to be able to store both of the post variable in the url for as it stands only one of them can be stored at a particular time:

```
 <script>
            function showUser() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            function showUser2() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform2').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
```

Below is the php portion:

```
$person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
$allIds = '';
if($person!='')
{
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);
}


$person2  = isset($_POST['person2']) ? $_POST['person2'] : '';
$allIds2 = '';
if($person2!='')
{
    $allIds2 = implode(',', $person2);
}
```

If any clarification are needed let me know

Update:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showUser() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            function showUser2() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform2').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="testform">
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
                        <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
                                                <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>



        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

update

PHP entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
$allIds = '';
if($person!='')
{
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);
}


$person2  = isset($_POST['person2']) ? $_POST['person2'] : '';
$allIds2 = '';
if($person2!='')
{
    $allIds2 = implode(',', $person2);
}





include("includes/db.php"); 



global $con;


$sql= "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $allIds . "')) LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $allIds . "'))";
$get_crs_count = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCount);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs_count);
echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_rows ;
while($row_crs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    $crs_id = $row_crs['course_id'];
        $crs_cat = $row_crs['course_cat'];

    $crs_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

    $crs_title = $row_crs['course_title'];
        $crs_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
          $crs_city= $row_crs['course_city'];
                      $crs_category= $row_crs['course_cat1'];

          $crs_date= $row_crs['course_date1'];


$crs_sdesc= $row_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $crs_image = $row_crs['course_image'];
        $provider_image = $row_crs['provider_image'];


  echo " <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
     <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo2'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
 <center><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a> </center>
        </div>  

</div>

      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

courses:
[image]

Comment: how are `showUser` and `showUser2` being called?

Comment: thanks for your responsve. I've added an update under my initial post posting the entire html page, essentially I am trying to achieve this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp but with multiple checkboxes instead of a single select option'

Comment: well you would have to store the parameters of the first call on the server side using a session. However this would be a very fragile solution.

Can you not just send the parameter of the first request along with the one you are sending anyway?

Comment: hi thanks for your inquire. I know its fragile but i would like to use session as it will make it easier for me to retrieve variables on other pages. I am quite a rookie at this how would i work this out with session

Comment: for your courteousy i also posted the entire php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `serialize()` can accept both forms:

```
        function showUser() {
            var datastring = $('#testform, #testform2').serialize();
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getuser.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: datastring,
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#txtHint').html(res);
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your response delighted as always. So i am using just the form name would be different but the function associated with each input would remain the same. would there be any changes to the php page?

Comment: I've implementation your suggestion, and it works but the problem now I have is with two seperate post i can control the variable, in the sense that the first form would be for course duration and second would be for sub category. now it seems that both form refers to the same variable, which in this case how do i know which variable is associated with which form which would be useful in in working with the sql to display the result $sql= "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $allIds . "') OR course_SUBC1 IN ('" . ? . "')) LIMIT 10";

Comment: Are you trying to send just two inputs to your php page or all of the inputs from two separate forms?

Comment: Its quite simpler than seems. I am essentially trying to achieve this w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp  but the only difference is that I am using checkbox instead of a select option, and that there are two forms instead of one. I guess it will be all inputs from two seperate form as the number of inputs may vary but the form would remain (such as certain courses may have more sub categories than others where in that case more checkboxes would be shown). Essentially, this is baseline example, in reality il have 3 or 4 forms, but want to see how i can work with multiple forms

Comment: So, are your checkboxes supposed to submit the form?

Comment: no there is no submit , its all dynamic, when a checkbox is checked dynamically the result is displayed, just like when you select an option in the above example the results are dynamically displayed. To make it easier to understand, i've included a picture at the bottom of my initial post

Comment: Are you married to the idea of doing this with php and mysql, or are you open to other backend storage solutions?

Comment: i am not married to any particular solution, whatever works best, work best, the main reason i use mysql and php is because i need to grab the results from the database and populate it, but whatever solution works best for me

Comment: If it were me (and if you're not married to your current database / mySQL etc..), I would use parse.com. The service is free up to a significant amount of usage (which Ive never come close to) and it really simplifies everything. You can accomplish everything you need with just javascript/jquery.  See the below post if you're interested in that approach:

[Save and retrieve user input from database with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881449/save-and-retrieve-user-input-from-database-with-javascript/27882356)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73801/discussion-between-delightedd0d-and-jonathan-etienne).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but whole system is based around php and mysql and this is just a small component of the cms, so its nearly impossible to pivot at this point. so in that case i am married to this idea and unfortunatetly il have to make it work  as such and i truly appreciate your support in kindly helping me achieve this goal