# Best way to store data for website with dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm learning all the webdev, now for gaming community purpose I'm making a website which is similar to periodic table. It cointains for now about 25 "elements" but only blocks displayed without any info. 
I want to make it open a dialog box (can't find any other name for it), similar to wowhead's table which contains item's info but I wan't it open on click, not on hover, and want it to act like lightbox, open on middle of screen with background grayed out.
Number of elements will rise to about 80, and here is my question:
Should I make for every such an element html file, which will be dispalyed in dialog, or use data base for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is probably to simplest solution for the layout and the Modal (the popup box).

You really only need one modal.

1. You can give each of your "blocks" a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and store an `item id` there.
2. Then, when a user clicks a block, get the id from the attribute
3. use the id to get the information for the item from your database (myriad of ways to do that)
4. then populate that info into the modal.

Here's a contrived example (without the getting info from database part which could vary greatly depending on how you want to do that.)

```js
$('.container').on('click', '.block',function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    $('#blockId').html(id);
 $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
  
  
});
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.block{
  background-color:#ccc;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    
}
#blockId{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="block" data-id="123"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="block" data-id="456"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="block" data-id="789"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="block" data-id="234"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="block" data-id="567"></div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="block" data-id="678"></div></div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                 <h3>Modal header</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>The id of the block you clicked was <span id="blockId"></span> use that to get stuff from your database</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, also if you could suggest what database would suit for such a project, most of data will be static anyway so no need to edit them

Comment: I would reccomend http://Parse.com and using their [Javascript API](http://parse.com/docs/js/guide), you can see a simple demonstration [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881449/save-and-retrieve-user-input-from-database-with-javascript/27882356#27882356)